# Simple questionnaire app design in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am creating a small application which has a questionnaire form with several fields on it, two text fields and 3 radio buttons. The user would log in and can fill out the fields and select the radio buttons and click submit, this will save the values entered to my Mongo database under that particular user.

I am not really sure how to design this data model as I am new to Mongo/NoSQL. My first thought was to have a questions model where I would store my questions, the type of the question (text or radio) and the options for the radio buttons. Based on this I would then create my form and allow the user to populate it. Then have a separate (user) model so that when the user clicks submit, the values he selected would be stored under that particular user.

Am I correct in using this design?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can put the answers under the user, but you will need to track which questions the the answers go to. So you will need to create a relationship property from answer to question (or vice versa, depending on how you want to query the data.) Having one relationship is okay,but just keep in mind that relations aren't Mongo's stong point and if you find yourself adding more and more models and relationships, you may want to look into postgres or mysql as your database.

Comment: @88jayto thanks! In that case would I be better off to have the questions stored along with the answers under the user? Essentially my app would just be users and questionnaires, 1 user can have 1 or more questionnaires, so I was going to save the list of answers to each questionnaire in an array under the user.

Comment: The other option I was thinking was to have a questionnaire model which has all questions defined, and a user model. When a questionnaire is submitted it gets saved along with the id of the user who submitted it so there is a link between the two.

Comment: yeah that would probably work here is a simple model:

`User
{
 "username":xxxx,
 "firstName":xxxxx,
 "lastName":xxxxx,
 "answers":[
 {
  questionaireId:1
 },
 {
  questionaireId:2
 }]
}

Questions
{
 id: 1,
 name:"Basic questionare",
 questions:[
  {
   text:"What is your favorit color",
   type:"radio",
   possibleAnswers:['blue','red']
  },
  {
   text:"What is your favorit food",
   type:"radio",
   possibleAnswers:['apples','poo']
  }
 ]
}`

Comment: One further question, if I also add checkboxes, for example one question allows the user to check one or more checkboxes, would I have all checkboxes as separate questions or what type can I use for multiple checkboxes? Store them all in an array?

Comment: store them all in an array, similar to how I did it up there but give it a different type:`{ text:"What are your favorite colors?", type: "multiselect", possibleAnswers:['red','blue','green']}` Now on the webpage, have an if statement that will allows multiple checks if the question type is "multiselect".